# Choose an employee and show the days where he has a specific shift code , along with the employees with the same shift

Tags: google-sheets

For convenience,
Let's assume we have a shift schedule of a week.
Header has the days from Monday to Sunday, and the 1st column contains the names of the employees.

| Names | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Suturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Andreas** | 17-01 | DO | 22-06 | DO | 17-01 | 22-06 | 22-06 |
| **Bob** | 22-06 | 22-06 | 17-01 | DO | 22-06 | 09-17 | 09-17 |
| **Celia** | 09-17 | DO | 22-06 | 22-06 | DO | 17-01 | 17-01 |
| **Daniela** | 17-01 | 22-06 | 17-01 | DO | 22-06 | DO | 22-06 |
| **Elena** | 22-06 | DO | 09-17 | 09-17 | 09-17 | 22-06 | 09-17 |
| **Franc** | 09-17 | 09-17 | DO | 22-06 | DO | 09-17 | 22-06 |

I also have a in a cell a drop-down list with the names of all employees and once I select a name I want the following:

I want it to show me the days of the week where the agent I chose has the shift code "22-06" and below of each that day I would also want to show me the rest agents who will have the same shift.

For example if I choose agent "Andreas" then the result to be the following:

| Wednesday | Suturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Celia | Elena | Daniela |
|  |  | Franc |

I was trying to do that with query function but the selection of the column has to be given while here it depends on the name I will choose.

Is there any idea how I can make this?

Below you can find the link of the google spreadsheet that illustrates this example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvQL4GFuKM5HZXbUJ7bMpp40YD1QtNtHCXOAE2qoxcU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there must be a simpler way of doing this, but the below seems to work...

```
=arrayformula(let(
names,A2:A7,
days,B1:H1,
shift_tbl,B2:H7,
name_filt,B10,
shiftcode,"22-06",
names_by_shiftcode,if(shift_tbl=shiftcode,names,),
name_tbl,{Days;names_by_shiftcode},
bycol(filter(if(name_tbl<>name_filt,name_tbl,),bycol(name_tbl,lambda(each,or(each=name_filt)))),lambda(col,tocol(col,1)))))
```